# Amavis: No decoder for .F/No ext program for .F, tried: unfreeze, freeze -d, melt, fcat

Tags: debian, amavis, freeze

I am using amavis for my Debian 11 mailserver. I managed to set almost all configs correct but there is a problem scanning .F files because no decoder is found.

Starting amavis tells me:

> Jun 17 10:31:30 mail amavis[709]: Net::Server: Group Not Defined.
> Defaulting to EGID '120 120'
>
> Jun 17 10:31:30 mail amavis[709]: Net::Server: User Not Defined.
> Defaulting to EUID '112'
>
> Jun 17 10:31:30 mail amavis[709]: No ext program for .F, tried:
> unfreeze, freeze -d, melt, fcat
>
> Jun 17 10:31:30 mail amavis[709]: No decoder for .F
>
> Jun 17 10:31:30 mail amavis[709]: Using primary internal av scanner
> code for clamav-socket

I tried to install the [freeze](https://linux.die.net/man/1/freeze) tool via apt and from [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/utils/compress/) but no success. Apt doesn't know this tool because it's not part of debian [anymore? was it ever?] and compiling it via the makefile throws a lot of compiler errors. I don't even think the 2.50.0 version I linked is compatible with debian because the README tells it was built for SunOS 4.1.2, Xenix 2.3.2 and MS-DOS.

I know the .F file format is not used anymore but this error annoys me and I don't want to just comment it out. Also I found a few users trying to get rid of this error message and grant full functionality for amavis.

BONUS:
Am I able to set the Net::Server Group and User? I know this message is not critical and caused by the log-level of amavis but I also found a lot of posts online where no-one is able to set the Net::Server correctly. I'd like to get rid of this message too the proper way. Not just comment it out.
Also: Is the last message:

> Using primary internal av scanner code for clamav-socket

an info for regular behavior or an error?